# Forgot to remove breakpoints before submitting app to App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, itunes

I have uploaded an app with breakpoints to the app store. I forget to remove a breakpoint before uploading the app. Will the review team reject my app for this reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Break points are the settings of XCode (or other IDE) they are not included into ipa file.

Comment: Thank you for response. I just worried but now i am happy thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Break points are set in the project environment, not in the binary. As such, breakpoint are only effective on your environment when a debugger is attached. You can verify this by running your app in the simulator without using the 'start' button of Xcode (just press on your app's icon in the simulator).

The breakpoints are project settings and are not compiled with the target archive, so it will not leave your machine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be worried. Your app won't be rejected. Breakpoints are used for internal purposes. No relation with App Store thing.

Cheers!